# Can we do unit testing for the file I/o operations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, file-io

Can we do unit testing for the file I/o operations in C# using VS2010? Since the unit testing is not efficient to access the data layer, do we need to unit test operation or is there any mock or fake operations to do so

Answer (score 1):

You are talking more about intergration testing here when you need to actually access a file system or another system.

When unit testing you need to mock out something like this you need to use dependency injection using unity for example and a "mock" file system.

The following are some good places to look for code to mock the file system..

http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/

http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/

http://jolt.codeplex.com/

http://www.typemock.com/

General info on mocking ...

http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#ClassicalAndMockistTesting

And the following link shows how you would use Dependency injection with unity...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254091/Implementing-Microsoft-Unity-Design-Pattern

Kind regards

Matthew Zielonka

Answer (score 1):

Can you write something that looks like a Unit Test that will verify file I/O?  Absolutely.

But you probably shouldn't.

You want your Unit tests to be very fast and have as few external dependencies as possible.  File IO is very slow (relatively speaking) and will depend on a bunch of details about the file system.

Within your unit tests - you probably only care that your code successfully called the Write operation or called the .Close() method.  You can unit test that behaviour.

If you really want to test that your application does interact with the file system correctly - your question becomes about integration testing or end-to-end testing; but not unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

What does this mean? Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? A unit test should only test clearly defined units with clear and concise responsibility with as few dependencies as possible. It should never test any operation that needs references to file system, databases, etc. Use mocks/stubs for such occassions.

Here is a collection of mocks:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use